# Receive alarm in a fragment and update the UI

Tags: android

Since fragments are intended to encapsulate logic I decided to put BroadReceiver logic in my own fragment.

At first I setup an Alarm like it was shown in ApiDemos:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),OnAirPresentBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

OnAirPresentBroadcastReceiver receives the broadcast and the purpose of this broadcast is to update the fragment's UI. I'm stuck here - is it possible and how ?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Receiver you can post another Intent to your Activity. From the Activity you can access the Fragment with the FragmentManager.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
notificationIntent.putExtra("extra", "extra");
context.startActivityForResult(notificationIntent, 0);
```

It'll you'll get it on your Activity in:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    handleNotification(intent);

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

If your Activity is not running you'll have Extra's to your intent in OnCreate

To make sure your Activity is in foreground: (this code get the foreground Activity)

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
String name = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getShortClassName();
if (name.equals(".YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME")) 
    {
    //only now start your intent.
    }
```

Another direction you can try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),YOUR_ACTIVITY_HERE.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivitygetActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
```

Now the event you come in your Activity's onNewIntent function, if its active. That's not a full solution but that could be a nice direction.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I need to update it only when the activity is running in the foreground, because I can trigger updates in onResume method ?

Comment: btw context.startActivityForResult(notificationIntent, 0);  in onReceive method says "The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: If your activity is on the foreground then the onNewIntent function will get called. You'll need to check the status your application in the receiver if you don't want it to be sent. See my edited answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any edits applied. "the status your application" - my application can be active even if my activity is not

Comment: okay, thanks - I'll try it. But can you suggest anything more intuitive - I mean is it really has to be like that ? My goal is to ask an api at various moments and update UI.

Comment: @context.startActivityForResult@ this method isn't declared in the Context class

Comment: Sorry, I meant: context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: fine, I also had to add get_tasks permission. I'll try the frirst approach for a while - let me know if you've got anything else, please